# CopyWebpackPlugin copy contents of a directory into the output directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I want to use CopyWebpackPlugin to copy all the files from a `public/` directory to the `dist/` directory. However, I need to set my output path as `dist/` earlier in the configuration file. Here is my setup:

**`webpack.config.js`**

```js
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve('src/App.jsx'),
  output: {
    filename: 'js/index.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: 'public/**/*' },
    ]),
  ],
  ...
};
```

This is copying the entire `public/` directory into `dist/`. Instead, I'd like to copy the files and directories *within* `public/` to `dist/`. Is there a way to do this without individually listing each file?

Answer (score 4):

As always, my own stupidity never ceases to amaze me. I just replaced `{ from: 'public/**/*' }` with `{ from: 'public' }` and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Extending OP's answer.

`CopyWebpackPlugin` doesn't override the directory. If it encounters two folders that conflict, it merges their content in the destination directory.
We can use this to achieve the desired result.

```js
new CopyWebpackPlugin({
  from: dir.root("public")
})
```

This will attempt to copy the folder named `public` to the destination. Since they are folders, their content will be merged.

Comment: For anyone not sure what `dir` is in `dir.root("public")` , you can use the path module: `require('path').resolve(__dirname, 'public')`